# SVG tspan element + font-family style?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to specify the font family inside of a tspan element within an svg button. It doesn't seem to register and I have not been able to find any documentation on this. I have only found documentation for the text element inside of an svg. My numerous attempts have not resulted in the text matching the style of the rest of the site. I need it to use the thin version of the Raleway font from Google.

HTML

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 86 20" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
    <path id="thisID" d="M 80 5 A 100 100 0 0 0 22.2 27.2 L 37.58 42.58 A 80 80 0 0 1 80 27.2 Z"></path>
    <text font-family:"Raleway:thin" fill="gold">
        <defs>
    <style type="text/css">@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:thin');</style>
</defs>
         <textPath style="font-size:6pt;" xlink:href="#thisID" startOffset="63%" >
            <tspan dy="-6">Home</tspan>
      </textPath>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**A NEW ATTEMPT**

Hm, I attempted to use the method below without success. What am I missing here?

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 86 20" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <style type="text/css">
        <![CDATA[   

  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:thin');
              {font-family:Raleway}

             ]]> 
  </style>
  <g>
    <path onclick="window.location='index.html';" id="thisID" d="M 80 5 A 100 100 0 0 0 22.2 27.2 L 37.58 42.58 A 80 80 0 0 1 80 27.2 Z"></path>
    <text font-family:"Raleway:thin" fill="gold">
         <textPath style="font-size:6pt;" xlink:href="#thisID" startOffset="63%" >
            <tspan dy="-6">Home</tspan>
      </textPath>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare the font-family.

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 86 20" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <style type="text/css">
        <![CDATA[   
  
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:thin');
     text{font-family:Raleway}
     
             ]]> 
  </style>
  <g>
    <path id="thisID" d="M 80 5 A 100 100 0 0 0 22.2 27.2 L 37.58 42.58 A 80 80 0 0 1 80 27.2 Z"></path>
    <text font-family:"Raleway:thin" fill="gold">
<textPath style="font-size:6pt;" xlink:href="#thisID" startOffset="63%" >
            <tspan dy="-6">Home</tspan>
      </textPath>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and patience, as usual. I have posted another attempt using your method above, but for some reason I am unable to replicate your result. Can you see what I am missing in my code?